# Data is not fetching from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

First good aftrnoon to all, i know this site is not for tiny issues but i can not get why the data is not coming, i earlier used same code for data fetching but its not working..
any idea , any suggestion beyond the codeing would be apreciated.
lets have a look of my code..

```
$emel=$_SESSION['emailid'];

echo $select="SELECT * FROM red where email = '$emel'";
$query = mysql_query($select);
$ustous = mysql_fetch_row(query );
echo $ustous['name'] ;
```

i echo select query and thats fine showing result as:

```
SELECT * FROM red where email = 'tracymmt@makemytrip.com'
```

name, address etc are not displaying and browser did not showing any error...
help! Thanx in advance

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions - they are deprecated.

Comment: mysql_fetch_row(query ); doesn't have the dollar sign, should be mysql_fetch_row($query);

Comment: but that working for other fine..

Comment: which editor are you using? You can look for good IDEs which tell you which line having the error. Your $query variable at the mysql_fetch_row(query) is wrong.

Comment: no...its by mistake written here in actual code it is fine...and not working... :(

Comment: What result do you get when executing your query with sql-console? (or phpMyadmin or similar)

Comment: If you assign $select to query first and then echo $select - are there any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$emel=$_SESSION['emailid'];

$select="SELECT * FROM red where email = '$emel'";
$query = mysql_query($select);

$ustous = mysql_fetch_row($query);
   $yourVar1 = $ustous[0];
   $yourVar2 = $ustous[1];
   $yourVar3 = $ustous[2];
```

Comment: no...its by mistake written here in actual code it is fine...and not working... :(

Answer (score 2):

You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) if you wish to retrieve the values using the fields names in the array.

That would be the fixed code for your issue:

```
$emel=$_SESSION['emailid'];

$select="SELECT * FROM red where email = '$emel'";
$query = mysql_query($select);
$ustous = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $ustous['name'] ;
```

By the way, mysql_* functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5.0. You might want to use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

correct your $query var fistly as :

```
$ustous = mysql_fetch_row($query );
```

use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) instead of  [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) or print as `$ustous[0]`

fetch_assoc only returns an associative array that you can use as `$ustous['name']`

```
$emel=$_SESSION['emailid'];

echo $select="SELECT * FROM red where email = '$emel'";
$query = mysql_query($select);
$ustous = mysql_fetch_assoc($query );
echo $ustous['name'];
var_dump($ustous);
```

Comment: good ans sir,,, but my problem is still same...

Comment: are you sure you have a row with email='tracymmt@makemytrip.com' and have a 'name' column?

Comment: what is output after run the last code block in my answer?

Comment: SELECT * FROM student where email = 'ajaymmt@makemytrip.com'Ajayarray(24) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["uniq"]=> string(32) "wh3T61r3B2FKh16OTKpP8D75v3g5I2Z5" ["image"]=> string(0) "" ["name"]=> string(4) "Ajay" ["subscription"]=> string(0) "" ["age"]=> string(4) "Ajay" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["g_name"]=> string(4) "Aman" ["address"]=> string(6) "Dwarka" ["i_name"]=> string(3) "mmt" ["grade"]=> string(2) "12" string

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$emel=$_SESSION['emailid'];

echo $select="SELECT * FROM red where email = '$emel'";
$query = mysql_query($select);
$ustous = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $ustous['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your:

```
mysql_fetch_row(query );
```

didn't work is because it returns the result as an enumerated array. That is, it looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Name [2] => Email )
```

If you `print_r`.

You're trying to call the 'name' of an associative array in your code. So, you would want something like:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [Name] => Joe [email] => example@email.com )
```

So, you would want to use either `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_array()` and pass `MYSQL_ASSOC` as your second parameter for `mysql_fetch_array()`.

The following is useful if you just want to grab the name of the user:

```
$emel=$_SESSION['emailid'];

$select="SELECT * FROM red WHERE email = '$emel'";
$query = mysql_query($select);
$ustous = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $ustous['name'] ;
```

In case where you'd like to grab something else, say user login records, you may also want to consider running it through a loop in case there is more than one instance of data in the database.

Something like:

```
$emel=$_SESSION['emailid'];

$select="SELECT * FROM logins WHERE email = '$emel'";
$query = mysql_query($select);

echo "Login History <br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   echo $row['loginDate'];  
}
```

That's just a rough example.

I'd definitely recommend you take a look into PDO though. Jeffery Way from NetTuts+ offers [a great tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) on how to connect and pull from a database with PDO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ustous = mysql_fetch_row($query );
```